# Usando Struct em exercício linguagem C

Tags: c

/* Escrever um algoritmo que leia os dados de “N” pessoas
(nome, sexo, idade e saúde) e informe se está apta ou não
para cumprir o serviço militar obrigatório. Informe os totais. */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Pessoa
{
    char nome[30];
    char sexo[1]; // M = Masculino e F = Feminino
    int idade;
    char saude[5];
};

main()
{

    int quant; // Quantidade de pessoas

    printf("Digite a quantidade de pessoas: ");
    scanf("%d", &quant);

    struct Pessoa candidato[quant];

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\nNome: ");
        fgets(candidato[i].nome,30,stdin);

        printf("\nSexo: ");
        fgets(candidato[i].sexo,1,stdin);

        printf("\nIdade: ");
        scanf(" %d", &candidato[i].idade);

        printf("\nSaude: ");
        fgets(candidato[i].saude,5,stdin);

        if(candidato[i].idade >= 18 && candidato[i].saude == "boa")
        {
            printf("O %s, sexo %s com idade %d e com saude %s esta apto ao servico militar. \n\n",
                   candidato[i].nome, candidato[i].sexo, candidato[i].idade, candidato[i].saude);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

    } // fim do for

} // fim função main()
```

Mas, quando eu uso o `fflush` mostra "Nome: Sexo" (na mesma linha) como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: O `fflush(stdin)` so esta definido em Windows. Noutros sistemas nao funciona. Se quiseres uma solucao portavel deves tentar arranjar outra solucao.

Comment: Quando eu uso o fflush não mostra tipo Nome: Sexo (na mesma linha) como faço para resolver isso então?

Comment: A solucao mais simples sera usar `fgets()` para **todos** os inputs. Depois, em casos especificos, converter a string para inteiro com `sscanf()`.

Comment: fgets() o codeblocks não funciona. :(

Comment: Não tem sentido você declarar char sexo[1];. Quando você declara uma string você precisa prever o caractere terminador ('\0') e se você só prevê o tamanho 1 então não existe espaço para ele. Note que char sexo; (a variável tem espaço para um caractere) é bem diferente de char sexo[1]; (uma string de comprimento 1). Ao fazer gets(candidato[i].sexo);
você irá colocar o '\0' fora da área alocada para a variável. Utilize char sexo; e scanf("%c", &sexo);.

Comment: No futuro, quando você tiver uma dúvida parecida, não esqueça de mendionar qual o erro que está dando, qual a entrada que você está passando, qua; a saida que você desejava, etc. É bem mais difícil dar uma boa resposta se você só disser que "nao está funcionando direito"

Comment: Se a fgets não funcionou é porque você cometeu algum erro em sua utilização, provavelmente especificou erradamente seus parâmetros. Veja os detalhes em: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fgets.html

Comment: Desculpe, me ocupei com outras coisas.
Mas ainda estou sem sucesso nesse programa, continua exibindo de uma vez as três perguntas. 
Nome: Sexo: idade na mesma linha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. a definicao da struct fica melhor fora da funcao.
2. `char sexo[0]` tem espaco para zero letras. Para guardar "M" (ou "F") e o terminador precisas de, pelo menos, 2 caracteres
3. `for(i = 0; i <= quant; i++)` vai executar o ciclo uma vaz a mais do que necessario
4. Depois de ir buscar a idade com o `scanf()`, um ENTER fica "pendurado" no stream de input. A leitura seguinte apanha esse ENTER e devolve uma string vazia
5. Onde esta o resto do programa? ???
6. A funcao `gets()` nao deve ser usada. Por ter sido tao mal pensada esta funcao deixou de fazer parte do C Standard na ultima versao (poucos compiladores usam a versao mais recente do Standard)
7. Boa sorte e **diverte-te**!

Comment: Obrigado "pmg", mas o programa é só isso mesmo.
O char sexo[0] é só para M ou F mesmo. Pq o for vai da + 1 loop? Não entendi sobre o scanf da idade apesar que nele que ta dando pal mesmo. Se não usar o gets uso o que então?

Comment: Eu estava a referir-me a parte do "Informe os totais". `char sexo[0]` tem espaco para zero caracteres; a string `"M"` precisa de 2 caracteres. Imagina que `quant` seja 2; o `i` comeca em `0`, depois `1`, depois `2`, e depois termina: 3 vezes!! Em vez do `gets()` aconselho o [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html). o uso e semelhante ao do `gets()`; so precisas de ter atencao ao ENTER final.

Comment: Entendi sobre o laço e corrigir, então sexo[1] tem que ser assim? já mudei a função para fgets() também.

Comment: @phpricardo Em C as strings são terminadas por nulo (`\0`). Por isso você precisa de pelo menos `2` caracteres: um pra letra em si ("M" ou "F") e outra pro terminador. Se usar somente um, as funções que mexem com string vão escrever fora da região de memória da sua variável, aí qualquer coisa pode acontecer... (em geral, coisa ruim :P)

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tente (note a alocação dinâmica de memória):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Pessoa {
    char nome[31];
    char sexo; // M = Masculino e F = Feminino
    int idade;
    char saude[6];
};

main() {
    struct Pessoa *candidato;
    int quant; // Quantidade de pessoas
    int i;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de pessoas: ");
    scanf("%d", &quant);
    candidato = (struct Pessoa *) malloc(quant*sizeof(Pessoa));
    for(i=0; i<quant; i++)  {
        printf("\nNome: ");
        fgets(candidato[i].nome,30,stdin);
        printf("\nSexo: ");
        scanf("%c",&candidato[i].sexo);
        printf("\nIdade: ");
        scanf(" %d", &candidato[i].idade);
        printf("\nSaude: ");
        fgets(candidato[i].saude,5,stdin);
        if(candidato[i].idade >= 18 && strcmp(candidato[i].saude, "boa") == 0) {
            printf("O %s, sexo %c com idade %d e com saude %s esta apto ao servico militar. \n\n",
                   candidato[i].nome, candidato[i].sexo, candidato[i].idade, candidato[i].saude);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    } // fim do for
    free(candidato);
} // fim função main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma opção seria utilizar no lugar do `fgets` o comando `scanf`:

```
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",&candidato[i].nome);
```